Try to upload my product by api and a json to Bol but get an 400 error
I am trying to use the Bol API documentation to send my products directly to the platform with Make.com. I created a scenario where an Excel file is filled out and then sent to my WordPress site (which works) and simultaneously to the Bol API (https://api.bol.com/retailer/offers).
I tried 2 different json formats:
{
  "ean": "{{9.`12`}}",
  "condition": "{{9.`49`}}",
  "conditionComment": "Geen beschadigingen, gloednieuw",
  "referenceCode": "{{9.`21`}}",
  "onHoldByRetailer": false,
  "unknownProductTitle": "{{9.`0`}}",
  "description": "{{9.`23`}}",
  "pricing": {
    "bundlePrices": [
      {
        "quantity": 1,
        "price": {{9.`8`}}
      }
    ]
  },
  "stock": {
    "amount": {{9.`5`}},
    "managedByRetailer": true
  },
  "fulfilment": {
    "method": "{{9.`10`}}",
    "deliveryCode": "24uurs"
  }
}

and
{
  "language": "nl",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "id": "EAN",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "{{9.`12`}}"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "condition",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "{{9.`49`}}"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "referenceCode",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "{{9.`21`}}"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "onHoldByRetailer",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "unknownProductTitle",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "{{9.`0`}}"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "description",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "{{9.`23`}}"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "pricing",
      "values": [
        {
          "quantity": 1,
          "price": {{9.`8`}}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "stock",
      "values": [
        {
          "amount": {{9.`5`}},
          "managedByRetailer": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "fulfilment",
      "values": [
        {
          "method": "{{9.`10`}}",
          "deliveryCode": "24uurs"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

But still get a 400 error. Any one who can help me out?
ps. the {{9.5}} are my Make placeholders.
The last json i use:
{
  "ean": "{{9.`12`}}",
  "condition": {
    "name": "{{9.`49`}}",
    "category": "{{9.`49`}}"
  },
  "reference": "{{9.`21`}}",
  "onHoldByRetailer": false,
  "unknownProductTitle": "{{9.`0`}}",
  "pricing": {
    "bundlePrices": [
      {
        "quantity": 1,
        "unitPrice": {{9.`8`}}
      },
      {
        "quantity": 6,
        "unitPrice": {{9.`13`}}
      },
      {
        "quantity": 12,
        "unitPrice": {{9.`14`}}
      }
    ]
  },
  "stock": {
    "amount": {{9.`5`}},
    "managedByRetailer": false
  },
  "fulfilment": {
    "method": "{{9.`10`}}",
    "deliveryCode": "24uurs-21"
  }
}


Can't access https://api.bol.com/retailer/offers from my location, browser only says it got an invalid response.

The 400 is only the HTTP status code - go check what the response body contained, often there is more information available in there in a human-readable format.

you have documentation RTFM https://api.bol.com/retailer/public/redoc/v9/retailer.html#tag/Offers

"pricing": {
"bundlePrices": [
{
"quantity": 1,
"unitPrice": 9.99
}
]
}

you have incorrect json according to documentation. i dont want to post findings in answer that will attract negative feedbacks. compare your json with documentation example.

@PowerMouse, the Bol api is at v10, the documentation you send is for the v9.
I've changed the current contenttype to: application/vnd.retailer.v10+json, so then you need this: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/19794538/2s9YBxZwUC
But still get a 400 error, because of a jwt problem.

{
"ean": "{{9.12}}",
"condition": {
"name": "{{9.49}}",
"category": "{{9.49}}"
},
}
